# Install l2boost package with github_install

Tags: r, installation-package

I'm trying to install Ehrlinger's l2boost from github. I've tried using:

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github('l2boost',username='ehrlinger')
```

This gives the following output:

```
Installing github repo(s) l2boost/master from ehrlinger
Installing l2boost.zip from https://github.com/ehrlinger/l2boost/archive/master.zip
Installing l2boost
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD build  \
  "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcBoWGu\l2boost-master" --no-manual --no-resave-data 

* checking for file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcBoWGu\l2boost-master/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'l2boost':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
* building 'l2boost_0.19.tar.gz'

"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcBoWGu/l2boost_0.19.tar.gz" --library="C:/Program  \
  Files/R/R-2.15.3/library" --with-keep.source 

* installing *source* package 'l2boost' ...
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  'l2boost' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (l2boost)
```

The only error I notice is that it didn't find any help / man pages. However, it doesn't appear to have actually installed any of the functions:

```
> library(l2boost)
> predict.l2boost
Error: object 'predict.l2boost' not found
```

In `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\library\l2boost\R`, there are only three files: `l2boost`, `l2boost.rdb`, and `l2boost.rdx`. The `l2boost\data` folder atleast successfully installed `diabetes.rda`.

Why is neither the help nor the functions being installed? Is it possible to install this package using install_github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why the man pages aren't working but if you type

```
l2boost:::predict.l2boost
```

you will see the function. Here is an example (which should work) from the function definition available on github.

```
data(diabetes)
object <- l2boost(diabetes$x,diabetes$y, M=1000, nu=.01)
prd <- predict(object)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was incorrectly assuming that since R wasn't finding `predict.l2boost` (without the namespace) and similar functions, that it wasn't loading the functions. Installing the man pages would be nice, but is a secondary concern.